# How to create advanced android UI?

Tags: java, android

I'm starting to develop applications for android, but I can not draw advanced interfaces like this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/42/question1.png/

Could someone direct me to a tutorial, or show me examples of how to do the following layouts?

I can not understand how to create a button and create a separator line for it.

How to create a title for the section? I can not understand how to create a button and create a separator line for it. How can I create an expandable button? And how to put it all together into a single item like this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/820/questionqc.png/

Forgive my bad English and thank you.

Comment: You should learn the basics before tackling the Advanced stuff, its going to overwhelm you.

Comment: In the future you should embed images in your question rather then using a 3rd party image hosting site.

Comment: JoxTraex, thanks for the tip! But I already have knowledge of the android architecture, but my source of study deals with the GUI of the apps in a very superficial way. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images you have pasted is ofcourse not simple. But it is still doable without much difficulty. The trouble is only in laying out the whole elements properly. I will give a bare skeleton here:

1. Expand button and Add button could  be a `ImageButton`
2. Separator could be an `ImageView`
3. For the custom list item you can do something like this(I am writing it in some sort of pseudo xml):

   > <'RelativeLayout>
   >   <'ImageButton (expandButton) aligned ParentLeft /> 
   >   <'ImageButton (addButon) alignedParentRight /> 
   >   <'ImageView (separator) toLeftOf addButton />
   >   <'TextView (title) alignedParentTop, toRightOf expandButton, toLeftOf separator />
   >   <'LinearLayout alignedParentBottom, layout_below:title>
   >       <'TextView /> <'TextView /> <'TextView /> <'TextView />
   >   <'/LinearLayout> 
   >   <'/RelativeLayout>

Comment: Cool! Now I understand, I thought it was more complicated. Thank you!